# pandas match two columns and create another column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pivot, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with A ,B ,C columns.I want to compare B and C columns and create two columns Which are A-1(current row year -1) and A-2(current row year -2) where A is year column.

Example : In the dataframe for the year 1971 ,the B column has apple , orange
and C column has only apple and year 1970 has B -banana,apple and C-apple.
Now , for each row in the year 1971 we try to generate values for A-1(1970) , A-2(1969) column .In year (A-1)1970 , apple is captured in both B,C columns so we flag yes for first two rows of 1971 year then for third row it is flagged as no as there is no orange in the year 1970.

So for every row we consider the year(say 1971) and check the B  and C values and see whether that particular B value is also captured in C column in the year-1(1970) and year-2(1969 , in this case it will be nan as we dont any record with 1969 in our dataframe) and flag them accordingly.

dataframe  :

```
 A          B          C       D
1971       apple    apple      yes
1971       apple    apple      yes
1971       orange   nan        no
1970       banana   nan        no
1970       apple    apple      yes
1972       mango    mango      yes
1972       banana   banana     yes
1972       orange   orange     yes
1972       apple    apple      yes
1973       banana    nan       no
1973       mango     mango     yes
1973       apple     nan       no
1974       orange    nan       no
```

output:

```
 A          B          C       A-1    A-2
1971       apple    apple      yes    nan
1971       apple    apple      yes    nan
1971       orange   nan        no     nan
1970       banana   nan        nan    nan
1970       apple    apple      nan    nan
1972       mango    mango      no     no 
1972       banana   banana     no     no
1972       orange   orange     no     no
1972       apple    apple      yes    yes
1973       banana    nan       yes    no
1973       mango     mango     yes    no
1973       apple     nan       yes    yes
1974       orange    nan       no     yes
```

i cant figure out , please help me on this.

Comment: okay , i will edit this question in a moment

Comment: @unutbu , please look at the edited question and provide me a solution

Comment: I'm a little confused by your last sentence, *"So for every row we consider the year and check the B value..."*. Did you meant to say *"So for every row we consider the year and check the **B and C** values...."*? In other words, does a `yes` value indicate *both* B and C values are present for the corresponding year?

Comment: yes , my mistake i will recorrect the sentence and  one more thing  u should be clear is a yes value indicate both B and C values are present for the corresponding year -1 and corresponding year-2

Comment: please look at the edited question and feel free to comment if u need any clarification

Comment: Hope you are clear now  else let me know about it

Comment: I think the example you have given does not answer all combinations of scenarios yet. Can you change few more rows of example?

Comment: @najeem ,unutbu  i have edited to cover all the scenarios pls check it once

Comment: @unutbu , you are almost close but the last row (1972, 'banana', NaN) should have the values 'no' for A-1 and A-2 because the banana is not captured in C column.it can be yes  if and only if the banana is captured in both B and C columns.

Comment: kindly let me know if you have any questions

Comment: @unutbu , i have added one more column D if it occurs in both B,C then it is yes else it is no

Comment: can anyone answer this question

Comment: In your revised example, should `(1972, apple, apple, no, no)` actually be `(1972, apple, apple, yes, yes)`?

Comment: @unutbu , yes  you are perfectly correct , i will change it in a moment

Comment: @unutbu ,are you able to solve this problem ?

Comment: @unutbu , you gave a solution earlier in that code , u have line of code df.loc[match['index'], col] = 'yes' .where did u get index column in match dataframe ?

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
nan = np.nan
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1971, 1971, 1971, 1970, 1970, 1972, 1972, 1972, 1972, 1973, 1973, 1973, 1974], 'B': ['apple', 'apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'apple', 'mango', 'banana', 'orange', 'apple', 'banana', 'mango', 'apple', 'orange'], 'C': ['apple', 'apple', nan, nan, 'apple', 'mango', 'banana', 'orange', 'apple', nan, 'mango', nan, nan]})

# add an index column to the DataFrame
df = df.reset_index()
df['BC'] = np.where(df['B'] == df['C'], df['B'], nan)
A_min = df['A'].min()


for i in [1, 2]:
    col = 'A-{}'.format(i)
    col2 = 'Y+{}'.format(i)
    df[col2] = df['A']+i
    # fill with nans
    df[col] = nan
    # place 'no' except where there is no data for the year A-i
    mask = df['A']-i >= A_min
    df.loc[mask, col] = 'no'

    # place 'yes' where 'A','B' columns match 'Y+i','BC' columns
    match = pd.merge(df[['A','B','index']], df[[col2, 'BC']],
                     left_on=['A','B'], right_on=[col2,'BC'])
    df.loc[match['index'], col] = 'yes'
    
df = df.drop(['index', 'BC', 'Y+1', 'Y+2'], axis=1)    
print(df)
```

yields

```
       A       B       C  A-1  A-2
0   1971   apple   apple  yes  NaN
1   1971   apple   apple  yes  NaN
2   1971  orange     NaN   no  NaN
3   1970  banana     NaN  NaN  NaN
4   1970   apple   apple  NaN  NaN
5   1972   mango   mango   no   no
6   1972  banana  banana   no   no
7   1972  orange  orange   no   no
8   1972   apple   apple  yes  yes
9   1973  banana     NaN  yes   no
10  1973   mango   mango  yes   no
11  1973   apple     NaN  yes  yes
12  1974  orange     NaN   no  yes
```

---

### How it works:

First, let's add an index column to the DataFrame. It's purpose will become clearer later. (Note that I'm assuming here that your DataFrame's original index is uniquely valued. We'll be relying on that property later on...)

```
df = df.reset_index()
#     index     A       B       C
# 0       0  1971   apple   apple
# 1       1  1971   apple   apple
# 2       2  1971  orange     NaN
# 3       3  1970  banana     NaN
# 4       4  1970   apple   apple
# 5       5  1972   mango   mango
# 6       6  1972  banana  banana
# 7       7  1972  orange  orange
# 8       8  1972   apple   apple
# 9       9  1973  banana     NaN
# 10     10  1973   mango   mango
# 11     11  1973   apple     NaN
# 12     12  1974  orange     NaN
```

Since we want to identify rows with a particular value *which is the same* in both the `B` and `C` columns, let's make a `BC` column which is equal to `B` when `B` and `C` are equal, and `NaN` when they are not:

```
In [123]: df['BC'] = np.where(df['B'] == df['C'], df['B'], nan)
In [124]: df
Out[124]: 
    index     A       B       C      BC
0       0  1971   apple   apple   apple
1       1  1971   apple   apple   apple
2       2  1971  orange     NaN     NaN
3       3  1970  banana     NaN     NaN
4       4  1970   apple   apple   apple
5       5  1972   mango   mango   mango
6       6  1972  banana  banana  banana
7       7  1972  orange  orange  orange
8       8  1972   apple   apple   apple
9       9  1973  banana     NaN     NaN
10     10  1973   mango   mango   mango
11     11  1973   apple     NaN     NaN
12     12  1974  orange     NaN     NaN
```

Now, we are going to be matching rows from different years, so let's add a column to fix which years we are interested in comparing. For example, we will wish to compare rows when `A` is 1971 with rows when `Y+1` equals 1971:

```
In [125]: df['Y+1'] = df['A']+1; df
Out[125]: 
    index     A       B       C      BC   Y+1
0       0  1971   apple   apple   apple  1972
1       1  1971   apple   apple   apple  1972
2       2  1971  orange     NaN     NaN  1972
3       3  1970  banana     NaN     NaN  1971
4       4  1970   apple   apple   apple  1971
5       5  1972   mango   mango   mango  1973
6       6  1972  banana  banana  banana  1973
7       7  1972  orange  orange  orange  1973
8       8  1972   apple   apple   apple  1973
9       9  1973  banana     NaN     NaN  1974
10     10  1973   mango   mango   mango  1974
11     11  1973   apple     NaN     NaN  1974
12     12  1974  orange     NaN     NaN  1975
```

With this setup, we can identify rows which should be flagged 'yes' by merging `df` with itself,
matching columns `A` and `B` with columns `Y+1` and `BC`:

```
In [127]: pd.merge(df[['A','B','index']], df[['Y+1', 'BC']], left_on=['A','B'], right_on=['Y+1','BC'])
Out[127]: 
      A       B  index   Y+1      BC
0  1971   apple      0  1971   apple
1  1971   apple      1  1971   apple
2  1972   apple      8  1972   apple
3  1972   apple      8  1972   apple
4  1973  banana      9  1973  banana
5  1973   mango     10  1973   mango
6  1973   apple     11  1973   apple
```

Notice that the `index` column indicates the row indices that should contain `yes` in the `A-1` column. This is the purpose for using `df = df.reset_index()` above. Without it, we would have lost the original index when we merge.

Comment: Thank you for the reply , I will look into your solution ,i have edited the question to cover all the scenarios.pls check once if u want to have areview

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Code for your problem :-

```
import pandas as pd
import csv


colnames=['A','B','C']
df=pd.read_csv("file1.txt",header=None,delim_whitespace=True)
df.columns=colnames
#print(df.head())


# Below the lines of Code for subset extract in pandas.
df2=df.ix[:,['A','B','C']]
#print("first df2 head :",df2.head())

list1=[]
list2=[]

for i in range(len(df['A'])):

    valoneless=(df['A'][i])-1

    valtwoless=(df['A'][i]-2)

    if (any(df['A']==valoneless)):

        if (df['B'][i])==df['C'][i]:
                val1='yes'
                list1.append(val1)

        else :
            val1='No'
            list1.append(val1)

    else:
        val1 = 'nan'
        list1.append(val1)

    if (any(df['A'] == valtwoless)):

            if (df['B'][i]) == df['C'][i]:
                val2 = 'yes'
                list2.append(val2)

            else:
                val2 = 'No'
                list2.append(val2)

    else:
            val2 = 'nan'
            list2.append(val2)

df2['A-1']=list1
df2['A-2']=list2


print(df2.head())

df2.to_csv("firstcolumn.txt",index=False,sep=" ",na_rep='nan')
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply , I will check your solution and let you know whether it is working as per expected or not

Comment: I have another column which is customer name , this code has to work for each customer.above sample is for one customer.will the code work if i include the column customername ??